# Program activating the "else" clause despite condition being met (C)

Tags: c, floating-point, precision

So I've got the following code in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     printf("Please enter the heights of 3 players\n");
     float average;
     float height;
     for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
     {
         scanf("%f", &height);
         average+=height;
     }
     average = (float)((average + 2.06)/4);
     if (average<1.900 || average>2.100) printf("Illegal heights average, your average %.3f isn’t approved\n",average);
     else printf("Your heights average is %.3f, welcome to space jam tournament!!\n",average); 
    return 0;
}
```

Now, for most tests, it works just fine, however one test continually fails:

[image]

I'm completely baffled by it. Maybe it has something to do with the float variables? Would be glad for someone to help me out with this.
Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Apart from that, I'm no IEEE754 specialist, but calculating this by hand yields exactly 1.9, so by rounding errors, your `average` variable might be just a little less than your 1.9 literal.

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: due to your use of `float`s, this actually sums to 1.89999997615814208984375 or `0x1.e66666p+0` in hex format.  this is obviously less than 1.9 hence your test is failing